# How to set karate.env in Karate UI

Tags: karate

In Karate UI, I would like to set the field karate.env, for example with "release", but I have this message :
"skipping bootstrap configuration for env: release - could not find or read file: karate-config-release.js, prefix: CLASSPATH"

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is just a warning message. I realize this is confusing, so it will be removed in the next version.

There is an optional new feature where if this file exists - it will over-ride your "main" config: https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick answer Peter.

It seems that when a test is run a first time, and after that I change the karate.env, and I re-run the test a second time, it doesn't take the new env.

Comment: @Chris that shouldn't happen. time to refer you to this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will open a new issue.
I have 2 more questions : 
1/ when I set the karate.env and I click on another feature, the karate.env is empty
2/ Can I run more than one feature at the same time on Karate UI?

Comment: @Chris oh are you using the UI ? it may need some more fine tuning so please submit enhancement requests